Feature selection for logistic regression and random forest (using Orange - no coding)
I’m using Orange to create a prediction model for the Indian liver patient dataset (binary target variable – either has or does not have liver disease – with 580 instances and 10 features). I’m using two models (logistic regression and random forest).
What techniques would be appropriate here to decide which features to keep?
I was thinking of using the correlation matrix which show that the target’s correlation with gender and total proteins is -0.08 and -0.03 respectively. And also of using the rank widget in orange which gives the gain ratio for the features (0.006 and 0.001 respectively).
Some of the reading I’ve done suggests that the gain ratio should only be used for decision tree based models and not logistic regression. The rank widget also has the ability to rank features based on information gain, gini decrease, ANOVA, chi-squared, ReliefF and FCBF. Are any of these more relevant to the problem?

It is not a good idea to ask questions that are highly specific to specialized software (that I’ve never heard of) that implies you just want to know which buttons to click.  Your entire approach is problematic because feature selection is almost always a bad idea.  The sample size needed for accurate feature selection is probably 10x higher than yours.  You also failed to specify the numbers of cases and non-liver cases.

Thanks Frank, that's very helpful - that probably explains why I was struggling to find literature relevant to my problem.
